# Find range of values of k for which f(x) <= k for all real values of x

Tags: education, discriminant

Find the range of values of k for which f(x) <=k for all real values of x

```
   f(x) = -2x^2 + 8x + 17 
  -2x^2 + 8x + 17 <= k
   2x^2 - 8x -17 + k >=0
```

I have done, but unsure of the answer....

```
  D = b^2 -4ac > 0
    = 64 + 136 -8k >0
    k<200/8
```

Help please

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x) = -2x^2 + 8x + 17$

Then , $$ f(x)' = -4x+8$$
And $$f(x)'' = -4$$

Since $f(x)'' < 0$ , the function attains maximum value at 
$$ -4x+8 = 0 \implies x=2$$

At $x = 2, $

$$f(2) = (-2.2^2 + 8.2+17) = -8+16+17 = 25$$

So any value of $k\ge 25$ satisfies the relation.

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite

$$f(x) =-2(x-2)^2+25\le 25$$

Thus, $k\ge 25$.

In your approach, you should set $D\le 0$ because $f(x)$ and $y = k$ do not intersect or are tangential to each other, which leads to the same range for $k$.

Comment: How to determine that f(x) and y=k do not intersect? What is your approach to this type of question?

Comment: Given that $f(x) \le k$, the parabola $f(x)$ is always below or tangential to the horizontal line $y=k$. So, they do not intersect or tangential to each other.